# AWS Lambda + Gateway API + React JS

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, cors, fetch

I am trying to post to my dynamoDB using react however I am getting the following error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/getuserprofile' from 
origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the 
request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

First I have checked if this method works using the Lambda test.

I have also used `curl -v -X OPTIONS https://xxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/getuserprofile` and its output was:

```
`< HTTP/2 200
< date: 
< content-type: application/json
< content-length: 0
< x-amzn-requestid:
< access-control-allow-origin: *
< access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type,Authorization,X-Amz-Date,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token
< x-amz-apigw-id:
< access-control-allow-methods: DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT`
```

However, when I try the react.js fetch function it throws the error.

```
fetch("https://xxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/getuserprofile", {
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },      
  body: JSON.stringify({key1: email, name, message})
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log('Success:', data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

I have tried to add 'mode' inside the fetch function to no avail.
Any debugging advice would really help as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants to know the answer to my question:
It was because you have to redeploy for CORS to be taken into effect.

So:

1. Go to your API.
2. On the left menu bar go to Resources.
3. Click on your resource
4. Click action bar > Enable CORS
5. Stages > Deploy

Answer (score -1):

Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that uses additional HTTP headers to tell browsers to give a web application running at one origin, access to selected resources from a different origin. A web application executes a cross-origin HTTP request when it requests a resource that has a different origin (domain, protocol, or port) from its own.

Below is AWS documentation for CORS.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Comment: In my lambda node.js function I do have this CORS policy: callback(null, {
            statusCode: 201,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: params.Item.email,
                message: params.Item.message,
                username: params.Item.name,
            }),
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            }